# How to use multiple nginx rewrite flags

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a config like this in my nginx site configuration that is throwing a syntax error:

```
rewrite ^/favicon\.ico$ /static/ico/favicon.ico last permanent;
```

The idea was to make this the `last` rewrite rule that's processed, and to also configure it to return a permanent redirect.

Is there a trick for this?

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question...)

Looking at [the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), it appears the syntax takes the following form:

```
rewrite regex replacement [flag];
```

Alas, just one flag is allowed at a time. I've done some minor testing though, and it seems that when you use the `permanent` flag, you don't have to use the `last` flag.

So the result becomes:

```
rewrite ^/favicon\.ico$ /static/ico/favicon.ico permanent;
```